# Xcode how to exclude FOLDERS from compilation?

Tags: xcode, build, compilation, project, linker-flags

I saw [this](http://lists.apple.com/archives/xcode-users/2009/Jun/msg00153.html) and answers in stackO, but didn't find how to exclude folders.

I have 3 folders with a lot of .h , .m and .mm and i need to exclude them temporary, but not to remove references. How can i do that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From looking at the post you link to. Here is how you do it:

1. Go to Build Settings.
2. Press the plus button and select "Add User-Defined settings"

[image]

3. Give the new field the name of `EXCLUDED_SOURCE_FILE_NAMES`.

[image]

4. Add the path to the folder: `<Path>/FolderToIgnore/*`. The asterisk denotes *all* the file in the folder.

[image]

That should do it.

**Note:** Make sure you add this to the right target.

Comment: Yep, this works! In Xcode 9 there is already such `User-Defined setting`: **Build Settings> Build Options> Excluded Source File Names**

Comment: How to exclude folder only for release build?

Comment: @phnmnn, tap the arrow next to "Excluded Source File Names" and it will drop down to show `Debug` and `Release`.  You can provide different options for each.

Answer (score 7):

#### xcode 9.2

`Build Settings> Build Options> Excluded Source File Names`

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Can't comment, but wanted to note that, unless I'm doing something wrong, when using the `EXCLUDED_SOURCE_FILE_NAMES` build setting as explained in the other answered, excluding a folder using something like `*/Folder/*` won't exclude anything within sub-folders of `Folder`, but only files within it directly. If you had another folder, eg. `/Folder/Subfolder/`, you'd have to include `*/Folder/Subfolder/*` as well in order to exclude any files within it. At least this is the case in Xcode 10.3.

Example:

```
[Folder]
    item.txt
    [Subfolder]
        image.png
    info.plist
```

`*/Folder/*` would exclude `item.txt` and `info.plist`, but not `image.png`.

`*/Folder/Subfolder/*` would exclude `image.png`.

Comment: Check out [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55492478/8221836) that suggests dropping the asterisk to solve this problem.

Comment: Another solution is to use groups without folders for every subfolder in excluded directory

Comment: To exclude everything in a folder at the root level of the project called "Folder" (including its subfolders), simply specify `Folder` (no `/*`)

Answer (score 4):

*This answer covers only how to exclude the files from the build or the matching file patterns*.*Exclude from the path or the folder has currently not been implemented in the Xcode*

- Select the `editor`
- Select `Add Build Setting`
- In Add Build Setting select `Add User Defined Settings` for this *select the project for which you want to add the user defined settings*.
- Select the name of it as `EXCLUDED_SOURCE_FILE_NAMES`
- Set the value as *filename patterns,the files you want to exclude*.

**or**

You can use the *File Inspector* and in the *target membership* simply `uncheck` the file which you do not want to include in your build

Similarly the same thing can be done *compile sources* category where you can `select the file` which you want to `add` to your `build`.