# Run a project without accessing frameworks for real devices

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have an issue: I have built-in frameworks via "Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content" that work only on real devices, while their source code is not available and I can't create version for simulator. However, I need to run the project on the simulator, and the functionality that is associated with the frameworks is disabled for the simulator with:

```
#if targetEnvironment(simulator)
#else
import MyFramework
import MyFramework1 
#endif
```

However, when we try to start the project in simulator mode, I get an error -

> Building for iOS Simulator, but the linked and embedded framework
>   'Framework' was built for iOS.

At Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries for my target I selected `optional` status for MyFramework and MyFramework1

Any suggestion how to fix run for simulator without these frameworks are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found useful fix for my case. This fix is based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47822797/5928311). I just excluded the folder for the simulator (Any iOS Simulator SDK) where the frameworks are physically located. I've added path like this "$(SRCROOT)/my_project/my_libs/*"

[image]